# Firefox and IE - rectangles don't display in svg when dynamically loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, svg

My HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="map-container">
    <svg id="mapa" width="600" height="400"></svg>
</div>
```

Then, in Backbone, in the render function I populate the svg with some rectangles:

```
var mapa = $(this.el).find('#mapa');
$.post("./getElements", function(data) {
    $(mapa).html('<rect id="sector1" x="0px" y="0px" width="300px" height="200px" fill="gray" fill-opacity="0.1"/><rect id="sector1" x="301px" y="0px" width="300px" height="200px" fill="gray" fill-opacity="0.1"/><rect id="sector1" x="0px" y="201px" width="300px" height="200px" fill="gray" fill-opacity="0.1"/><rect id="sector1" x="301px" y="201px" width="300px" height="200px" fill="gray" fill-opacity="0.1"/>');
 });
```

Later on I would like to take the elements from database. For now it works fine in Chrome, but Firefox and IE don't display a single thing - but if I copy-paste the code directly to the html file, it works fine, so I don't think it's any kind of a typo.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Don't use .html to add SVG elements. html only works for html elements in Firefox and IE currently. The specification has changed though and at some point Firefox and IE will support this.

Comment: Ok, thank you, it makes sense now. What can I use instead of .html in this case? I tried .append but without success.

Comment: DOMParser, but you'll need to set a namespace on the root element to use it. Or alternatively use standard DOM createElementNS and setAttribute

Answer (score 0):

One alternative besides createElementNS would be to use `.html()` for the whole `<svg>` element:

```js
$(".map-container").html('<svg>' + /* svg content */  + '</svg>')
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/silverwind/g71bfdnm/).